# how to send variable from javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, controller, twig

I'm working with symfony2 and I need to send data from javascript function to the controller.

This works when there is no data to send in the url

```
document.location.href="{{path("modifMalade")}}"
```

But I don't know how to do to put parameter on it?

Comment: Maybe this will help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899097/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-the-url

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just to read the docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path

In your case, it could look like this:

```
document.location.href="{{ path("modifMalade", {'param1': 'value1'})}}"
```