# How can I implement an add/edit parameter mechanism?

Tags: php, url, url-parameters

Assume this is my current URL:

```
http://example.com/search?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

Now I want to add `param3=baz`. So this is the code:

```
<a href="?param3=baz" >add param3</a>
//=> http://example.com/search?param3=baz
```

See? `param1` and `param2` will be removed. So I have to handle it like this:

```
<?php
    $query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
    $query_params = $query_params == '' ? '?' : $query_params . '&';
?>

<a href="?{$query_params}param3=baz" >add param3</a>
```

Seems ugly, but ok, nevermind. Now what happens if a parameter be already exist and I need to edit it? Assume this example:

```
http://example.com/search?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

Now how can I make a link which edits the value of `parame2`? *(plus keeping other parameters)*

Comment: how you come to know that this time i want to edit already existing and this time i want to add new-one?Means it's almost impossible to find-out the mood

Comment: @stack ..... http_build_query() use...  for ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809774/manipulate-a-url-string-by-adding-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to write a relative URI that preserves the existing query string while adding additional parameters to it.

You have to Do again:

```
search?param1=foo&param=bar&param3=baz
```

**Or**

> Using Javascript is Possible

[How to add a parameter to the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899097/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-the-url)

**Or**

```
function currentUrl() {
    $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
    $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    return $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;
}
```

Then add your value with something like;

```
echo currentUrl().'&param3=baz';
```

**or**

> Whatever GET parameters you had will still be there and if `param3` was a
>   parameter before it will be overwritten, otherwise it will be included
>   at the end.

```
http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array("param3"=>"baz")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `http_build_query` to generate new query, like this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/search?param1=foo&param2=bar';

$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $params);

$data = [
    'param3' => 'baz'
];

$params = array_merge($params, $data);

echo http_build_query($params) . "\n";
```

And output will be:

```
param1=foo&param2=bar&param3=baz
```

I use `array_merge` for override exist params, if we get url:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/search?param1=foo&param3=bar';
```

The same code output will be:

```
param1=foo&param3=baz
```

We override exist param and save old params.